# Import active record model in non-active record ruby file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use a active record model `Mymodel < ActiveRecord::Base` in a ruby file, but the ruby file is already in the models directory in my Rails App. when I call `model = MyModel.new` I get an error. do I need to import anything in the plain ruby file?

Comment: Can you add some code example or explain it a bit more please? :)

Answer (score 0):

if in the root of your project, try writing:

```
require './config/environment/'
```

Comment: no, the ruby file itself. you have to load your project environment in order for you to access the AR model inside this file.

Comment: I am getting this: `require': cannot load such file -- ./config/environment/ (LoadError)

Comment: There should not be a trailing slash.

Comment: found it ( I think.. ) it is require '../../config/environment/'